# Why is my quizzcount doubling its value

Tags: java

I'm having a problem with this code in that the quizzcount variable is not outputting the correct value, it doubles the value.

I found a work around by diving the quizzcount by 2 and it works but i would really like to figure out why its doubling the value.

So for example, without dividing quizzcount by 2, if the user gets 7 out of the 10 questions correct the messagedialog will display that the user got 14 out of 10 correct.

What is causing this?

Thanks guys, any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InvalidClassException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.NotSerializableException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import java.awt.* ;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.lang.*;

public class MathFiles extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
private ObjectOutputStream toFile;
private String name;
private boolean open;
private static String response;
private static int menuOption = 0;
private static int numberOfMaths = 0;
private FileInputStream fis;
private ObjectInputStream fromFile;
Math aMath = null;
private int quizcount =0;
String checkbutton = "";
private static int tracker =1;
int count = 0;
int fimage =0;


JRadioButton questA, questB, questC, questD, questE;
ButtonGroup  questGroup;
JPanel       questPanel;

JLabel       question;
JPanel       questionPanel;

JTextField   resultText;
JLabel       resultLabl;
JPanel       resultPanel;

JButton      nextButton;
JPanel       quizPanel;

ImageIcon    image;
JLabel       imageLabl;
JPanel       imagePanel;

JTextArea    questionText;
JScrollPane  scrollPane;

Random       rand;



/** @param fileName is the desired name for the binary file. */
public MathFiles()
{
    setTitle( "Math Quiz Competition" );

    rand = new Random();
    toFile = null;
    //tracker =  rand.nextInt(5)+1;
    tracker = 1;


    name = "Quiz"+tracker+".txt";
    open = false;

    //openFile(); //Use only when creating file
    //writeMathsToTextFile(name);
    setLayout( new FlowLayout() ); 
    inputFile();
    beginquiz();
    showquestions();
    setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );   

} // end MathFiles constructor


/** Writes all Maths from a text file and writes them to a binary file.
    @param fileName the text file */
public void writeMathsToTextFile(String fileName)
{
    Scanner inputFile = null;
    Math nextMath = null;
    String question_num;
    String question;
    String answera;
    String answerb;
    String answerc;
    String answerd;
    String answer_cor;
    String file_name;
    String SENTINEL ="DONE";


    try
    {
        inputFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Text file " + fileName + " not found.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Question number: ");
    question_num = keyboard.nextLine();
    while (!question_num.equalsIgnoreCase(SENTINEL))
    {

     System.out.print("Question: ");
     question = keyboard.nextLine();

     System.out.print("Answer A: ");
     answera = keyboard.nextLine();

     System.out.print("Answer B: ");
     answerb = keyboard.nextLine();

     System.out.print("Answer C: ");
     answerc = keyboard.nextLine();

     System.out.print("Answer D: ");
     answerd = keyboard.nextLine();

     fimage = rand.nextInt(30)+1;
     file_name = "image"+fimage+".gif";
     System.out.print(file_name);

     System.out.print("Correct Answer: ");
     answer_cor = keyboard.nextLine();



     nextMath = new Math(question_num, question, answera, answerb, 
                answerc, answerd, answer_cor, file_name);
     writeAnObject(nextMath);
     numberOfMaths++;

     System.out.print("\nQuestion number: ");
     question_num = keyboard.nextLine();
    } // end while


    System.out.println("successfully created = " + name);
} // end readMathsFromTextFile




/** Opens the binary file for output. */
public void openFile()
{
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(name);
        toFile = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        open = true;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot find, create, or open the file " + name);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        open = false;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error opening the file " + name);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        open = false;
    }
    //System.out.println("successfully opened = " + name);
} // end openFile



/** Writes the given object to the binary file. */
public void writeAnObject(Serializable anObject)
{
    try
    {
        if (open)
            toFile.writeObject(anObject);
    }
    catch (InvalidClassException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Serialization problem in writeAnObject.");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch (IOException e)

    {
        System.out.println("Error writing the file " + name);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
} // end writeAnObject

public void result()
{
    System.out.println("Your score is");

}



public void inputFile()
{

    try
    {
        fromFile = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(name));

    }

    catch(StreamCorruptedException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error in input stream: " + name);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error reading input stream: " + name);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
} // end displayFile




/** Closes the binary file. */
public void closeFile()
{
    System.out.println("closed name = " + name);
    try
    {
        toFile.close();
        open = false;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error closing the file " + name);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
} // end closeFile

/** @return the fileâˆšâ‰ s name as a string */
public String getName()
{
    return name;
} // end getName

/** @return true if the file is open */
public boolean isOpen()
{
    return open;
} // end isOpen

public void beginquiz()
{

    try
    {
        aMath = (Math)fromFile.readObject();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("The class Math is not found.");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch(StreamCorruptedException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error in input stream: " + name);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error reading input stream: " + name);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }  

}

void showquestions()
{

    //question group
    /*question  = new JLabel();
    question.setText(aMath.getquestion());
    question.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
    question.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    questionPanel = new JPanel();
    questionPanel.add( question );*/

    questionText  = new JTextArea(5,20);
    questionText.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    questionText.setLineWrap(true);
    questionText.setText(aMath.getquestion());
    questionText.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
    questionText.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    questionPanel = new JPanel();
    questionPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(questionPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    questionPanel.add( questionText );


    // quest group
    questA = new JRadioButton(aMath.getanswera(), false );
    questB = new JRadioButton(aMath.getanswerb(), false );
    questC = new JRadioButton(aMath.getanswerc(), false );
    questD = new JRadioButton(aMath.getanswerd(), false );


    questGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    questGroup.add( questA ); 
    questGroup.add( questB );
    questGroup.add( questC ); 
    questGroup.add( questD );


    questPanel = new JPanel();
    questPanel.setLayout( new BoxLayout( questPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS ) );
    questPanel.add( new JLabel("Choose the Correct Answer") );
    questPanel.add( questA ); 
    questPanel.add( questB );
    questPanel.add( questC ); 
    questPanel.add( questD );



    // result panel
    //resultText  = new JTextField(20);
    //resultText.setEditable( false );   
    //resultLabl  = new JLabel("Result");
    //resultPanel = new JPanel();
    //resultPanel.add( resultLabl );
    //resultPanel.add( resultText );


    //button
    nextButton = new JButton("Next");
    quizPanel = new JPanel();
    quizPanel.add(nextButton);


   //Image image1 = new ImageIcon("image/image1.gif").getImage();
    image = new ImageIcon("image1.gif");
    imageLabl=new JLabel(image);
    imagePanel = new JPanel();
    imagePanel.add(imageLabl);

    // frame:  use default layout manager
    add( imagePanel);
    add( questionPanel);
    add( questPanel);
    //add( resultPanel);

    questA.setActionCommand(aMath.getanswera());
    questB.setActionCommand(aMath.getanswerb());
    questC.setActionCommand(aMath.getanswerc());
    questD.setActionCommand(aMath.getanswerd());

    questA.addActionListener(this);
    questB.addActionListener(this);
    questC.addActionListener(this);
    questD.addActionListener(this);


    nextButton.setActionCommand( "next" );   // set the  command 

    // register the buttonDemo frame
    // as the listener for both Buttons.
    nextButton.addActionListener( this );
    add(quizPanel);

}

public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent evt)
{
  //evt.getActionCommand() = aMath.getanswer_cor();


if (questA.isSelected()&& 
    aMath.getanswera().equalsIgnoreCase(aMath.getanswer_cor().trim()))
    quizcount++;

if (questB.isSelected()&& 
    aMath.getanswerb().equalsIgnoreCase(aMath.getanswer_cor().trim()))
    quizcount++; 

if (questC.isSelected()&& 
    aMath.getanswerc().equalsIgnoreCase(aMath.getanswer_cor().trim()))  
    quizcount++; 

if (questD.isSelected()&& 
   aMath.getanswerd().equalsIgnoreCase(aMath.getanswer_cor().trim()))
   quizcount++;


if(questA.isSelected() || questB.isSelected() || questC.isSelected() || questD.isSelected())


 if ( evt.getActionCommand().equals( "next" ))
{

   try
    {
        aMath = (Math)fromFile.readObject();      
        questionText.setText(aMath.getquestion());
        questA.setText(aMath.getanswera());
        questB.setText(aMath.getanswerb());
        questC.setText(aMath.getanswerc());
        questD.setText(aMath.getanswerd());
        imageLabl.setIcon(new ImageIcon(aMath.getfile()));

        questGroup.clearSelection();  

        repaint();

    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("The class Math is not found.");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch(StreamCorruptedException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error in input stream: " + name);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        if (count<=0)
           count = 0;
        else 
           count--;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your score is "+quizcount/2 +" out of 10");
        try{
          Thread.sleep(2000);
          System.exit(0);
        }catch (InterruptedException em) { }
    }  




}



}



public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    MathFiles mat = new MathFiles();
    mat.setSize( 450, 550 );  
    mat.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    mat.setResizable( false ); 
    mat.setVisible( true ); 
}

} // end MathFiles


class Math implements java.io.Serializable
{
private String question_num;
private String question;
private String answera;
private String answerb;
private String answerc;
private String answerd;
private String answer_cor;
private String file_name;




public Math(String quesno, String quest, String ansa, String ansb, String ansc, 
         String ansd, String ans_cor, String file) 
{

   question_num = quesno;
   question = quest;
   answera = ansa; 
   answerb = ansb; 
   answerc = ansc; 
   answerd = ansd; 
   answer_cor = ans_cor; 
   file_name = file;
}           



public void setquestion(String lName)
{
    question = lName;
} // end setquestion


public void setquestion_num(String fName)
{
    question_num = fName;
} // end setquestion_num

public void setanswera(String add)
{
    answera = add;
} // end setanswera


public void setanswerb(String cty)
{
    answerb = cty;
} // end setanswerb


public void setanswerc(String st)
{
    answerc = st;
} // end setanswerc


public void setanswerd(String z)
{
    answerd = z;
} // end setanswerd


public void setanswer_cor(String phn)
{
    answer_cor = phn;
} // end setanswer_corr


public String getquestion_num()
{
    return question_num;
} // end getquestion_num

/** @return the question */
public String getquestion()
{
    return question;
} // end getquestion

/** @return the answera*/
public String getanswera()
{
    return answera;
} // end getanswera

/** @return the answerb */
public String getanswerb()
{
    return answerb;
} // end getanswerb


public String getanswerc()
{
    return answerc;
} // end getanswerc


public String getanswerd()
{
    return answerd;
} // end getanswerd


public String getanswer_cor()
{
    return answer_cor;
} // end getanswer_corr

public String getfile()
{
    return file_name;
} // end getanswer_corr




/** @return the Math information */
public String toString()
{
    String myMath = getquestion_num() + " " + getquestion() + "\n";
    myMath += getanswera() + "\n";
    myMath += getanswerb() + " " + getanswerc() + " " + getanswerd() + "\n";
    myMath += getanswer_cor() + "\n";
    myMath += getfile() + "\n";

    return myMath;
} // end toString

} // end Math
```

Comment: Is `actionPerformed` being called twice when you expect it to be called only once?  Perhaps you accidentally called `addActionListener` twice?  Without more code, this is a guess.

Comment: Where is quizcount initialized?

Comment: This is the kind of problem that a debugger is perfect for

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information. `quizcount` is external to the code you've posted so we can't tell if it's initialized correctly, whether you call this method more than once, or if something else changes it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is that you've registered ActionListeners on the radio buttons. This means the event fires when you select an answer as well as clicking the 'next' button. With that in mind it should be obvious why your score is doubling itself.

As far as I can tell you don't need ActionListeners for the radio buttons. You should only be checking the answer when the user has indicated they are done with their selection. That the score is exactly doubling itself also suggests that you basically haven't tested the program besides naively selecting a radio button and clicking 'next'. Before commenting out the lines where you add the listeners to the radio buttons, try changing your answer. Open the program, select the correct answer, then select an incorrect answer, then select the correct answer again and click 'next'. See what happens.

This kind of error can also be easily found with a debugger. Just insert a breakpoint inside actionPerformed and it will be obvious it's being called by more than one action.